# creating a wrapper of similar to ID card

Tags: html, css

I am struggling with creation of a collection of elements wrapped inside a single one. I made a sketch of what i was trying to create.

[image]

The HTML would look like this:

```
<div class="wrapper-1">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <h3 class="title">HEY NOW</h3>
  <p class="text">you a rock star, hey now! You are a rock star</p>
</div>
```

What would be the best way to create such a wrapper?

Comment: you can float the image box  and modify the BFC for the container and text https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context example from your HTML http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/yVLJPE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to create two columns as `.left-side` and `.right-side` inside the main wrapper and add the contents to the these columns as following:

```
<div class="wrapper-1">
  <div class="left-side">
    <div class="image"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="right-side">
    <h3 class="title">HEY NOW</h3>
    <p class="text">you a rock star, hey now! You are a rock star</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the fully implemented version:

```css
.wrapper-1 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
}

.left-side {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.left-side > .image {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/100x100) no-repeat center center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.right-side {
  float: left;
  width: 285px;
  height: 100px;
}

.right-side > .title {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-1">
  <div class="left-side">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>
  
  <div class="right-side">
    <h3 class="title">HEY NOW</h3>
    <p class="text">you a rock star, hey now! You are a rock star</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this, using `flexbox`

```css
.wrapper-1 {
  display: flex;
}
.wrapper-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}
.wrapper-1 .image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/100/00f);
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-1">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="wrapper-2">
    <h3 class="title">HEY NOW</h3>
    <p class="text">you a rock star, hey now! You are a rock star</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And if you can't change markup, use `position: absolute`

```css
.wrapper-1 {
  padding-left: 110px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper-1 .image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/100/00f);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-1">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <h3 class="title">HEY NOW</h3>
  <p class="text">you a rock star, hey now! You are a rock star</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete solution:

HTML:

```
    <div class="wrapper clearfix">
        <div class="left">
            <img src="img.png">
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <h3>text</h3>
            <p>text text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}

* html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */

.wrapper {
   box-sizing: border-box; /* makes padding go on the inside */
   padding: 10px; /* gives interior padding */
   width: 1170px; /* whatever width you want the container to be */
   margin: 0 auto; /* center it */
   background-color: #fff;
}

.left {
   width: 20%; /* whatever width you want the left side to be, stick to percentages */
   float: left;
}

.left img {
   width: 100%; 
   height: auto;
}

.right {
   width: 77%; /* whatever width you want the right side to be, stick to percentages, notice that 77% and 20% dont add up to 100%, this is to account for the small gap inbetween the divs */ 
   float: right;
}
```

Note: "clearfix" is used when floating things left and right. It prevents the common error where the div collapses in itself when child divs are being floated.

working jsfiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzugsh9z/)